# How to understand word "Astrology" in a film actor profile?

Tags: word-usage

One day I saw a film, and I'm interested in one of the actors. Then of course I googled him, in its actor profile, I read "Astrology : cancer". What does Astrology mean in this circumstance? Does that mean this actor is now having cancer illness?

Comment: It should read _Cancer_ as it is a proper noun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(From Wikipedia) "Astrology is a pseudoscience that claims to divine information about human affairs and terrestrial events by studying the movements and relative positions of celestial objects...
Cancer (♋︎) is the fourth astrological sign in the Zodiac, originating from the constellation of Cancer. It spans from 90° to 120° celestial longitude. Under the tropical zodiac, the Sun transits this area between approximately June 22 and July 22." (Further information: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astrology)

In short, it means that the actor's birthday is sometime between June 22 and July 22, and some people believe that you can determine personality traits and advice based on that. It has nothing to do with the disease cancer.